# Sending stomp message to client on every http request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I have a spring boot server and a client which are connected via Websockets using STOMP.

My use case is that I want to send data to the client, every time a http request to a specific endpoint is made.
All the tutorials I found, only show the case, that the client sends some data to "/hello" and the server reacts by sending data to "topic/greetings":

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
}
```

What I need is a controller method that sends data without the need of the message mapping. It should just send data to the client every time someone performs a get request to the endpoint. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate msgTemplate;

@SendTo("topic/data-received")
@RequestMapping(value = "/send-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendData(@RequestHeader(value = "id") String id,
                               @RequestHeader(value = "data") String data) {

    User user = new User();
    user.id = UUID.fromString(id);
    user.stringData = data;
    database.saveStringData(user);
    msgTemplate.convertAndSend("topic/data-received", "data sent!!");
    return "successful";
}
```

Here is my client code:

```
function connect() {
var socket = new SockJS('/clipboard-websocket');
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('topic/data-received/', function (message) {
        alert("Data received!!");
    });
}
```

And that's my WebSocket config:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/clipboard-websocket").withSockJS();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trailing slash is missing in the destination

```
msgTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/data-received", "data sent!!");
```

[image]

[github-repo-issue-54498776](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/issue-54498776-simp-stomp-issue)

Comment: thanks a lot for your work! unfortunately that didn't solve the problem yet.

Comment: I had a missing slash somewhere else in the project. Works now ;)